# Ruby not connecting to IMAP account

Tags: ruby, imap, ruby-2.0

I’m trying to write a Ruby script that goes through an IMAP server, and I have set this up as test case. For some reason, though, I can’t get it to actually find the port. I’ve even tried running `getaddrinfo`, with no luck. It simply won’t acknowledge the server’s existence.

```rb
require 'net/imap'

test = File.new "test.txt", 'w'

imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.google.com', 993, usessl=true, certs=nil, verify=false)
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'user', 'pass')
imap.examine('Mail')

imap.search(["SMS"]).each do |msg|
    test << msg
end
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [ruby-gmail](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail)

Comment: @fotanus: I'd rather use a built in library for portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is imap.gmail.com or imap.googlemail.com